# Adding x days to today's date where x is too big to convert

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I haven't managed to find a work around, so hopefully this hasn't been asked before.

I'm trying to get what the date will be x days from today, however I've encountered an issue where my x value is too big:
`OverflowError: int too big to convert`

I've tried the two methods below and both have the same issue, does anyone know a good work around?

```
pd.to_datetime('today') + datetime.timedelta(days=137200)
pd.to_datetime('today') + pd.Timedelta(137200, unit='D')
```

Comment: See pd.Timestamp.min and pd.Timestamp.max to see what the limits are. Basically the nanoseconds you can store around year 1970 in a signed 64bit int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If working with days is possible use [`Timestamp.to_period`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.to_period.html) for convert datetime to [`Period`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/timeseries.html#representing-out-of-bounds-spans), so then only add number of days:

```
d = pd.to_datetime('today').to_period('d') + 137200
print (d)
2396-12-04
```

---

```
d = pd.to_datetime('today').to_period('d') + 1372000
print (d)
5777-09-10
```